# Redirect to PHP script using POST and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, authentication

I've found so many answers to this question, yet none of them seem to fit my needs.

I'm handling user authentication via Javascript, and the access token which I need to pass around is acquired via a Javascript SDK. What I want to do is pass the access token to an HTML/PHP page via the POST method so that the token is not exposed in the URL. This needs to occur in a javascript callback so that I can redirect the user only on successful authentication.

All of the suggestions I've seen have suggested manually setting an href variable with the data I'm passing declared in the URL, but I can't use this solution as this will expose my data.

How can I acquire a token via JS, post it to a PHP script, and display the page associated with that script without exposing the token to the user?

Here's my attempt at the solution using only a username as an example:

```
$.ajax({
        data: 'username=' + username,
        url: 'confirmation.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(msg) {
            //Not sure what to do here
        }
});
```

Comment: You can't not expose it to the user. It's always available for the user to see via the browser console. Your attempt should at least make it not visible in the url, but the user will still be able to see it in the request body. (assuming you're using jquery 1.9 or later, since prior to 1.9 the `method` option didn't exist.)

Comment: Well that's problematic. I assume I'm going against standard convention by using a JS SDK for authentication, then?

Comment: I mean.. if the user gets said credentials, they can only do what said credentials are allowed to do, correct? And the user is logging in to said system with their own credentials correct? Where's the problem?

Comment: Firebase Auth for example works in a similar way. The user logs in, all client side, via the Firebase javascript sdk, which gives a token that allows the user to perform actions they are authorized to do. It doesn't really matter if the user gets the token, because they still can only do the things they are authorized to do.

Comment: I suppose that's true. I'm still getting the hang of Web Authentication, so forgive me if my concerns aren't relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ajax code isn't correct. You might wanna try something like this:

```
    $.ajax({type : "POST",
        url : "confirmation.php",
        data : { username :  username},
        success : function(result){
           window.location.replace("your_redirected_site_here");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("-- ERROR IN AJAX --\n\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

ofcourse this ONLY checks if the ajax code works and has something that has been sent back. I wouldn't recommend using it like this. Why not use a form with a hidden field that you only fill up once it has to be sent? Then your controller (hoping your using MVC) can handle the authentication and if succesfull redirect to a new page.

an example of the javascript code

```
    <script>
    var authenticationToken; //you can still fill this with your own code

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hiddenField').val(authenticationToken);
        myform.submit();
});
</script>

<form name="myform" action="yourControllerPage.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="" id="hiddenField"/>
</form>
```

do note that I use Jquery!

Comment: `data : { username :  username},` and `data: "username=somevalue"` are essentially identical. the former just auto-encodes the value for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ;)

Answer (score -1):

put the access token in the header of your request

```
var accessToken = getAccessToken();
$.ajax({
    data: 'username=' + username,
    url: 'confirmation.php',
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken, 
        contentType: "application/json"
    },
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(msg) {
        //Not sure what to do here
        window.location.href = "/the/url/you/want/to/send/them/to.html";
    }
```

});